# XML Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't know whether I am doing in a correct way or not. But I just tried to use namespace in `xml`. When i try to transform xml to xsl am getting this error `XML Content is not allowed in prolog`

This is my `xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees xmlns:pi="urn:com.sdsd/picof">
    <pi:PayGroup>
    <pi:Header>
        <pi:Version>19</pi:Version>
        <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>ADSDP</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
        <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>ADSDP</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
        <pi:Pay_Group_ID>US1</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
        <pi:Pay_Group_Name>US1 Salaried</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
        <pi:Pay_Period_Start>2015-02-01-07:00</pi:Pay_Period_Start>
        <pi:Pay_Period_End>2015-02-14-07:00</pi:Pay_Period_End>
        <pi:Updated_From>2015-02-05T06:03:48.000-07:00</pi:Updated_From>
        <pi:Updated_To>2015-02-06T19:47:39.457-07:00</pi:Updated_To>
        <pi:All_Effective>false</pi:All_Effective>
    </pi:Header>
    </pi:PayGroup>
 </pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees>
```

This is my `xsl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xd" xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">

<xsl:template match="/pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees/PayGroup/Header">
<folder>
    <file>
        <item><xsl:value-of select="Version"/></item>
        <item><xsl:value-of select="Payroll_Company_ID"/></item>
    </file>
    <file>
        <item><xsl:value-of select="Pay_Group_ID"/></item>
        <item><xsl:value-of select="Pay_Period_Start"/></item>
    </file>
</folder>
</xsl:template>
```

Could someone guide me if i do it in a wrong way?

Comment: The code you have reproduced here does _not_ cause this error. Make sure you show the code _exactly_ as it is in your editor, including whitespace. The error message has nothing to do with namespaces - it is due to characters in front of the XML declaration (which is forbidden).

Comment: @MathiasMüller But if i try without namespace then it is working fine. could you guide me with simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your template to be applied then make sure you use the prefix in all steps:

`<xsl:template match="/pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees/pi:PayGroup/pi:Header"> <folder> <file> <item><xsl:value-of select="pi:Version"/></item> <item><xsl:value-of select="pi:Payroll_Company_ID"/></item> </file> <file> <item><xsl:value-of select="pi:Pay_Group_ID"/></item> <item><xsl:value-of select="pi:Pay_Period_Start"/></item> </file> </folder> </xsl:template>`